# Program opens 9 messageboxes while I only want 1

Tags: c#, messagebox

When my timer reaches a number of seconds (10, 20 or 30) I want a messagebox to appear. This works but instead of just 1 messagebox, 9 appear! I have no idea why?

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hrs = sw.Elapsed.Hours, mins = sw.Elapsed.Minutes, secs = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
        label5.Text = "";

        if (mins < 60)
            label5.Text += "0" + mins + ":";
        else
            label5.Text += mins + ":";

        if(secs < 60)
            label5.Text += secs;  

       else if(secs < 60)
            label5.Text += secs;

        if (comboBox1.Text == "10 seconden") // maximale tijd per beurt instellen.
            if (mins == 00 && secs == 10)
                MessageBox.Show("Je tijd is op!");

        if (comboBox1.Text == "20 seconden")
            if (mins == 00 && secs == 20)
                MessageBox.Show("Je tijd is op");

        if (comboBox1.Text == "30 seconden")
            if (mins == 00 && secs == 30)
                MessageBox.Show("Je tijd is op");
```

Comment: I suspect that you have multiple event subscriptions, please post a piece of code where you create/subscribe your timer. Side note: you have some duplicating code here, consider simpler logic.

Comment: Problem already solved :), i just had to change the timer interval form 100 to 1000.

Comment: Why would changing the interval change the behaviour?

Comment: I think it is because it showed a messagebox for not only the tenth second but also 10.1 , 10.2 , 10.3 until 10.9. That also explains the 9 messageboxes ;)

Comment: You'd be better off following my advice and disabling the timer when you show a message box. And then you can run your timer at higher frequency.

Answer (score 5):

Hard to be 100% sure what's going on. Most likely, I think, is that the timer is still running when you call `MessageBox.Show`. And `MessageBox.Show` runs a modal message loop which results in timer events firing. And they execute and show the message box again. And again. And again.

If you have a timer event handler that pumps the message queue, as you do, you need to disable the timer, at least while you pump the message queue, to avoid such re-entrancy.